# How to run Virtual PC 2007 on Windows 7 64 bits

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a virtual server client, which is Windows Server 2008.

I have run it using Virtual PC 2007. Now I am on Windows 7, how can I use the Windows Virtual PC to run it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to download this: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx

Install and then just run your VPC.

Comment: Yes, it runs only Windows XP mode.

Answer (score 0):

You were at the correct link.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx

Notice the link above the language selection? It says **Don’t need XP Mode and want VPC only? Download Windows Virtual PC without Windows XP Mode**.

Click that.  Then download.